# Working with IComparable.Compare without magic numbers

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style, code-readability, base-class-library

I really hate working with [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) - to this day, after years of working with .Net, I still get regularly confused by those 1s and -1s.

**Can I somehow replace the [Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.compare.aspx) result values with some self-explanatory names** without having to cast the output integers to something else after every [Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.compare.aspx) call?

I tried to define an enum like this:

```
public enum ComparerResult
{
    ALessThanB = -1,
    Equal = 0,
    AGreaterThanB = 1
}

if(comparer.Compare(a, b) == ComparerResult.ALessThanB)
```

But that of course won't compile without a cast.

This of course also applies to [IComparable.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer this to express less-than:

```
if (comparer.Compare(a, b) < 0)
```

This is a nice mnemonic because you use the same operator for comparison with zero as you would between the two operands.

---

As Reddog reminded me in the comments, the specification for the interfaces does not require -1 and 1 specifically; it only requires negative and positive results.  As such, the logic you're currently using is not guaranteed to work in all cases.

Comment: This is also good because the value returned doesn't necessarily have to be -1, 0, or 1. It only has to be less than zero, zero, or greater than zero.

Comment: @Reddog, actually, yes, I just checked the spec for the method and it does not guarantee that it will return -1 or 1 specifically.

Answer (score 2):

How about just creating constants? That way you won't have to cast from an enum.

```
public class CompareHelper
{
    public const int ALessThanB = -1;
    public const int Equal = 0;
    public const int AGreaterThanB = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about an extension method on `IComparable` and `IComparer` ?

```
public static class IComparableExtension
{
    public static ComparerResult NiceCompareTo(this IComparable a, IComparable b)
    {
        int result = a.CompareTo(b);
        if (result > 0) return ComparerResult.ALessThanB;
        if (result < 0) return ComparerResult.AGreaterThanB;
        return ComparerResult.Equal;
    }
}

public static class IComparerExtension
{
    public static ComparerResult NiceCompare(this IComparer c, IComparable a, IComparable b)
    {
        int result = c.Compare(a, b);
        if (result > 0) return ComparerResult.ALessThanB;
        if (result < 0) return ComparerResult.AGreaterThanB;
        return ComparerResult.Equal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using constants is dangerous.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.compare.aspx) for IComparer.Compare only specifies that the return value should be "less than zero" if `x < y`, or "greater than zero" if `x > y`.  So you should not assume that the return value will be one of [-1, 0, 1].

What I would suggest instead is creating an extension method on IComparer that does the work for you.

```
static MyCompare(this IComparable self, object x, object y)
{
    var result = self.Compare(x, y);
    if(result < 0) return ComparerResult.ALessthanB;
    if(result == 0) return ComparerResult.Equal;
    return ComparerResult.AGreaterThanB;
}
```